# How to delete duplicate values?

Tags: excel, vba

I dynamically update the cells in columns A and B, and join both values on each row (using &) and place the values in column C.

My purpose is fulfilled by detecting duplicate names when firstName (Column A values) and LastName (column B values) are entered twice. An empty value (observed when the msgbox is displayed) pops up when I delete the duplicate name followed by the first occurrence.

This is an issue at times, especially because sometimes the msgbox does not go away. ie the code crashes.

How can I prevent the empty value, or msgBox from being displayed? I suspect something is wrong with my if statement.

VBA code I placed in the worksheet

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("c1:c12"), Target.Offset(0, 1).Value) > 1 And _
  Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <> " " Then
    MsgBox Target.Offset(0, 1).Value & " is a Duplicate Entry" & vbNewLine & _
    " ENTER A NEW NAME", vbInformation, "Duplicate Detected"
    Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = " "
    Target.Offset(0, 0).Select
ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("c1:c12"), Target.Offset(0, 2).Value) > 1 And _
  Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <> " " Then
    MsgBox Target.Offset(0, 2).Value & " is a Duplicate Entry" & vbNewLine & _
    " ENTER A NEW NAME", vbInformation, "Duplicate Detected"
    Target.Offset(0, 0).Value = " "
    Target.Offset(0, 0).Select
Else: Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your value a blank space (*Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <> " "*) or IsEmpty(Target.Offset(0, 1)) your intention?

Comment: either gives the same result, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: you'll need to put in some more safety lines in your code, which should prevent the crash, e.g., *If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub*, as you could be having issues with just specifying the target.  Additionally, *If Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub* would also only run the code for column C.  my guess is that the offset values on the target, possible generated from an undesired target, fulfill some criteria, and that provides some issue, though I don't know how that would inherently crash your code.

Comment: Are you possibly triggering each messagebox?

Comment: You're combining in C and looking to offset -1 and -2 for your checks... just caught that as i went to type the code out in my answer.  offset(0,1) from C is D, and offset(0,2) from C is E.  You have stated that first names are in A, last names are in B.

Comment: heyy.... i have tried your advise but Im still having the issue....still giving an empty string... and still crashing,

Comment: Please update your post with your modified code.  I have input an answer with the hopes that it might alleviate your issue.  Given your description, the "blank" msgbox was showing up after deletion, which should require a whole row being selected, and the target.count should have resolved that from running the macro.  Maybe describe in slightly more detail what you have done and when the error occurs (provide any error codes if those have been showing up, though it looks like you're crashing excel given your original post)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i wanted to create a sheet with

```
-2        -1       0
ColA      ColB     ColC
First1    Last1    First1Last1
First2    Last2    First2Last2
First3    Last3    First3Last3
First4    Last4
```

I would personally start with conditional formatting for ColC to flag what is a duplicate, in case there is an issue, which circumvents a messagebox.

If i did need a messagebox, i would set up similar to what you have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Application.CountIfs(Range("C1:C12"),Target.Value) > 1 Then 'checks for first/last name
        MsgBox("The name " & Target.Offset(0,-2).Value & " " & Target.Offset(0,-1).Value & " already exists." & vbNewLine & "Please enter a new name.")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Edit1:**

Given the data entry for colA and colB, would this be more appropriate?  I utilized the row of the target, so the negative offset shouldn't be of concern, since you know that colA is first name and colB is last name.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim r as long
    r = target.row
    If isempty(cells(r,1)) or isempty(cells(r,2)) then exitsub
    If Application.CountIfs(Range("B1:B12"),cells(r,2).Value,Range("A1:A12"),cells(r,1).Value) > 1 Then 'checks for first/last name
        MsgBox("The name " & cells(r,1).Value & " " & cells(r,2).Value & " already exists." & vbNewLine & "Please enter a new name.")
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Edit2:**

In verifying the use of no values and some values, this macro has been working for my testing (i added the clear contents and .select so you are back on the line you should be adding data); i also added a range specification related to the intersect in case you are adding values like first/last to a random place outside of a1:b12:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(12, 2))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Long
    r = Target.Row
    If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1)) Or IsEmpty(Cells(r, 2)) Then Exit Sub
    If Application.CountIfs(Range("B1:B12"), Cells(r, 2).Value, Range("A1:A12"), Cells(r, 1).Value) > 1 Then 'checks for first/last name
        MsgBox ("The name " & Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & Cells(r, 2).Value & " already exists." & vbNewLine & "Please enter a new name.")
        Cells(r, 1).ClearContents
        Cells(r, 2).ClearContents
        Cells(r, 1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes Edit 1 is a much better idea!  Thanks much Cyril. The code knocks off 2 main factors: I don't have to worry about adding a new column, and my code does not crash!

Comment: Glad that worked for you!  If this resolved your issue or got you where you need to be, please mark as answered so this question can be listed as Answered in the inquiry queue.

Comment: hello Again the program still crashes

Comment: .... I don't know how exactly but during my testing, by putting repeated last names and/or first names and leaving the other field(s) blank, a black cell is still displayed and/then also eventually crashes.

Comment: please update your post with the whole updated sub, as an edit.  given I was testing this yesterday and not having issues with my edit 1, i want to see with what you're working.  my only other initial issue is to ensure that your target is within the range a1:b12...

Comment: What about testing for first names only as an additional feature  ?

Comment: I will say that would be a separate question, though i'll try to direct you a bit.  the 2 lines directly after *r = Target.Row* would need to be modified, as well as the messagebox.  Essentially you won't care what is in colB if you're assessing colA.  Your bigger issue is having both as a change event and not triggering BOTH scenarios.  Only one type of change event can occur per worksheet (e.g., selection change, change, double click, etc.).  I would highly recommend using conditional formatting for the other scenarios (assessing first/last name individually).

Comment: `If Application.CountIf(Range("B1:B12"), Cells(r, 2).Value) > 1 Then 'checks for first name
        MsgBox ("The name " & Cells(r, 1).Value & " " & Cells(r, 2).Value & " already exists." & vbNewLine & "Please enter a new name.")
        Cells(r, 1).ClearContents
        Cells(r, 2).ClearContents
        Cells(r, 1).Select
    End If` ' i was trying this as an alternative but it didnt work thats why i asked

Comment: Two things:  1)  if you want to use that, ensure that you only have 1 worksheet_change() within the worksheet, and 2) watch the uses of each column (1 = A =  first name, 2 = B = last name).  Try posting another question specific to adding ADDITIONAL worksheet_change() items to an existing worksheet_change event, since you need to put in some if-statements or switches to ensure only one is activated at a time, preventing msgbox spam, etc.